# Cocoa Facebook login not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

My APP's Facebook login wont work and I cant seem to figure out why.

In my `.h` file i added `#import "FBConnect.h"` and `@interface MyImageViewControllerViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>` and i have my `Facebook *facebook;` iVar.

I implement all of the methods that are required (As said in the Tutorial) this is how I did it. ( I wont post everything coz I think it'll be pointless)

```
-(BOOL)facebooking{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APP_ID andDelegate:self];    
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];  

}
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
} 
return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

UIAlertView *a = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Token" message:[facebook accessToken] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[a show];

}
```

Now when I call the `facebooking` method it starts up the safari on my `Facebook APP` auth page, i press `Okay` it goes back to my `iOS` app but for some reason the `fbDidLogin` isn't called. neither is `fbDidNotLogin`. Is there a place that i need to point to them somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implementing this methode ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

Comment: yes, that and `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}`

Comment: you must implement juste one of this two methode, thie first For iOS 4.2+, the second else

Comment: try to implement all these methodes in your application delegate

Comment: ya i guess you have to implement the session in the app Delegate... thank you for the help.